# Increment version on project build

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In Android Studio I have in `build.gradle` default info about application version:

```
android {    
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 24
        versionName "0.1 beta"
    }
}
```

How can I increment the `versionCode` automatilcally on each project compilation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting from [my book](http://commonsware.com/Android):

Since the `android:versionCode` is a monotonically increasing integer,
one approach for automating it is to simply increment it on each build.
While this may seem wasteful, two billion builds is a *lot* of builds,
so a solo developer is unlikely to run out. Synchronizing such `versionCode`
values across a team will get a bit more complex, but for an individual
case (developer, build server, etc.), it is eminently doable using Groovy.

The
[`Gradle/HelloVersioning`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/HelloVersioning)
sample project uses a `version.properties` file as the backing store for the
version information:

```
def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

    def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + 1

    versionProps['VERSION_CODE']=code.toString()
    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode code
        versionName "1.1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}
else {
    throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
}
```

First, we try to open a `version.properties` file and fail if it does not
exist, requiring the developer to create a starter file manually:

```
VERSION_CODE=1
```

Of course, a more robust implementation of this script would handle this case and
supply a starter value for the developer.

The script then uses the read-the-custom-properties logic illustrated
in the preceding section **[NOTE: of the book, not included here]** to read the existing
value... but it increments the old value by 1 to get the new code to use.
The revised code is then written back to the properties file before it
is applied in the `defaultConfig` block.

In this case, the script throws a `GradleException` to halt the build if
the `version.properties` file could not be found or otherwise could not be
read.

Comment: To add to CommonsWare's answer, if you get "Could not read version.properties!" create one manually in `your_project/app/version.properties`.